# Python client hanging when sending empty message to server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, subprocess, client-server

I have a python reverse shell that I am working on that utilizes a client-server connection using TCP. I am testing them both right now on my localhost windows machine and I am utilizing the subprocess library to handle commands. The client is supposed to send a command to the server and the server will reply back with the output.

Server:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os

# Server

# creates TCP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# port and server ip(localhost)
LOCAL_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5565

BUFFER_SIZE = 5000  # size of message

no_char_message = "-1: Please enter a command"


# test connection
print("Server starting up on %s with port number %s" % (LOCAL_HOST, PORT))
# bind socket to ip and port
sock.bind((LOCAL_HOST, PORT))
# listen to socket
sock.listen(1)

# socket will accept connection and client address

print("Waiting for connection")  # waiting for connection
connection, address = sock.accept()  # accept connection with client address
print("Connected to", address)  # connected by address
while True:
    command = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)  # receive message from client
    if not command:
        break
    if len(command) == 0:
        connection.send(str.encode(no_char_message))
    if len(command) > 0:
        terminal = subprocess.Popen(command[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = terminal.stdout.read() + terminal.stderr.read()
        output_as_string = str(output, "utf-8")
        connection.send(str.encode(output_as_string))
        print(output_as_string)
print("Closing Server")
sock.close()
connection.close()
```

Client

```
import socket

# Client
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # creates TCP Socket

# local host and port
LOCAL_HOST = '127.0.0.1'

PORT = 5565
BUFFER_SIZE = 5000  # size of message

# connect socket to ip and port
sock.connect((LOCAL_HOST, PORT))
print("Connected to server\n")
while True:

    message = input("Please enter a command:\n")  # ask user to input message
    if message == 'quit':
        break
    print("Sending %s" % message)
    sock.send(str.encode(message))  # send message
    command = str(sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE), "utf-8")  # receive message
    print("received %s" % command)
print("closing connection with server")
sock.close()
```

The issue is when I send an empty message to the server it hangs and just says sending in the terminal and the server never receives anything. I am not sure what is causing this but I am assuming the pipes are being blocked or that I am not handling this correctly.

I want the server to return an error message to the client rather than handle the message error in the client itself.

I tried checking the condition if the length of the command is 0 and handling it with an error message but it did not work and still hangs.

The program also seems to hang when I try for example the date command.

In general, how do I handle the condition if a command is not recognized, empty or doesn't execute successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP has no concept of an empty message. TCP has no concept of a message at all, it knows only bytes. Thus, if you call send with an empty string it will simply send nothing (not an empty packet but no packet at all) to the server which means that there is nothing for the server to receive - it will still block while waiting for data. In other words: there is no empty command, there is simply no comment at all.

```
if len(command) == 0:
```

This will not check for an empty message (which again does not exist) but will trigger if the client closes the connection. Any check for an empty command had to be done at the client already.